# C - How to check if at least one neighbor of a cell in a matrix respects a predication?

Tags: c, matrix, cell

I'm on a project where I have to code a little game named "recolor", basically it's grid of a certain size, the grid is divided in cells (we have size*size cells), I can play a color (the color have to be in the grid or in the authorized colors) and each time I'm playing a color the grid will change from the top letf corner to color each cells directly connected to the top left corner that has the same color.
That's for the global context, now I already have all the functions to play this game but I have some problems with the function I use to play a move:
The game is defined using this type :

```
struct game_s
{
    color **grid;
    color **initial_grid;
    uint width;
    uint height;
    uint nmb_cur_mv;
    uint nmb_mv_max;
};
```

```
/*
* Def : 
*   - neighbour_of_origin checks if a cell is in the neighborhood of the (0,0) of the game grid, to be in the neighborhood
*     the cell should have the same color as the (0,0) and the cell and (0,0) have to be connected by a path of cells that have the same
*     color as (0,0).
* Param :
*   - cgame g : the game grid
*   - int x, y : coordinates of the cell we are currently checking
*   - bool** to_change_tab : 2D array of boolean that represent the game grid and have the same size as it. It is used to mark all the cells to
*                            modify. By default the whole grid is set to false except (0,0) which is changed no matter what.
* Ret :
*   - void function, nothing to return.
*/
void neighbour_of_origin(cgame g, int x, int y, bool **to_change_tab)
{
    assert(g);
    assert(g->grid);
    assert(to_change_tab);
    color origin = g->grid[0][0];
    int offset[4][2] = {
        {-1, 0}, /*W*/
        {0, 1},  /*S*/
        {1, 0},  /*E*/
        {0, -1}  /*N*/
    };
    int off_x;
    int off_y;
    for (int elem = 0; elem < 4; elem++)
    {
        off_x = x + offset[elem][0]; /*takes the 'x' coord in the offset matrix and add it to the current x*/
        off_y = y + offset[elem][1]; /*takes the 'y' coord in the offset matrix and add it to the current y*/
        if (((off_x >= 0 && off_x < SIZE) && (off_y >= 0 && off_y < SIZE)) && (to_change_tab[off_x][off_y] == true) && (g->grid[x][y] == origin))
        {        
            to_change_tab[x][y] = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}

/*
* Def : 
*   - game_play_one_move will change all the cells that are neighbors of the (0,0)that have the same color as it. The changing always begin
      from the (0,0) and then it expands in all directions.
* Param :
*   - game g : the game grid that will be modified.
*   - color c : the color that will be applied to all the cells we have to change.
* Ret :
*   - void function, nothing to return.
*/
void game_play_one_move(game g, color c)
{
    assert(g);
    assert(g->grid);
    bool **to_change_tab = (bool **)malloc(sizeof(bool *) * SIZE);
    assert(to_change_tab);
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        to_change_tab[i] = (bool *)malloc(sizeof(bool) * SIZE);
        assert(to_change_tab[i]);
        for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
        {
            to_change_tab[i][j] = false;
        }
    }
    /*getting all the cells we have to change*/
    to_change_tab[0][0] = true; /*(0,0) is always modified */
    printf("mark tab : \n");
    for (int x = 0; x < SIZE; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < SIZE; y++)
        {
            neighbour_of_origin(g, x, y, to_change_tab);
            printf("%d ", to_change_tab[x][y]); /*debbuging purpose*/
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    /*modification of the game grid */
    for (int x = 0; x < SIZE; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < SIZE; y++)
        {
            if (to_change_tab[x][y] == true)
            {
                g->grid[x][y] = c;
            }
        }
    }
    g->nmb_cur_mv += 1;
    /*free the temporary array of bools*/
    for (int x = 0; x < SIZE; x++)
    {
        free(to_change_tab[x]);
        to_change_tab[x] = NULL;
    }
    free(to_change_tab);
    to_change_tab = NULL;
}
```

above we have the two functions I've made to change the color as described in the rules, It actually works pretty well but I have a big issue on it.

This is my grid at the very begining :
each number corresponds to a color, the grid is 12*12 cells.

```
000202101030
033111132010
101232320332
231032111220
212333320100
033011233213
112220013112
131310101333
030100211130
131000323100
133112232002
202301112301
```

Here is my grid when I play the following colors : 3 1 3 0

```
000202101030
000000002010
000202020332
230002111220
212300020100
033011233213
112220013112
131310101333
030100211130
131000323100
133112232002
202301112301
```

if I play any color (except 0 of course) as my next move I expect every 0 connected to the top left to change but i got this instead:

```
333202101030
333333332010
333232320332
233332111220
212333320100
033011233213
112220013112
131310101333
030100211130
131000323100
133112232002
202301112301
```

the 0 on the first line didn't changed whereas they were connected to the origin, I suspected that the bug is in my condition in `neighbour_of_origin(cgame g, int x, int y, bool **to_change_tab)` because i'm using a for on x and y so the first line is evaluated first and the 0 on the first line did not have any neighbor that corresponds to the if condition at this state, is there a way to evaluate  in "the order of propagation",I wanted to rewrite it recursively but I'm really bad in recursion.
Very sorry for the long post, I wish someone could help me, have a good day.

edit : I got a ''''fix'''' I duplicate my for loops in the `game_play_one_move()` function so it will loop again and again to find each cells he couldn't find before, I know it's not a real fix because in the future i don't know how the grid will be displayed exactly, but i guess that a loop that will check again and again until it can't find any neighbor could be a solution too, in terms of colplexity it would be a real problem since i'm looping in the grid again and again and again

Comment: I didn't read all your code, but I guess you loop over your grid from top to bottom, and left to right? So, when you change the color you should check the cells above and left. If it's the old color change it, and recursivly check it's neighbor.

Comment: in the provided code i'm just doing a loop form top to bottom, i've fixed that adding loop left to right and another top to bottom and it works but as I said I'm really skilled when it comes to recursion even more if it's recursion through loops